# Change color in table row depending on cell value in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am doing a table of history transactions. In my transaction db I have a column named `QuantityChange`. Where values can be negative or positive.

I would like to set the row color to red, if its a minus value and green if positive (or zero).

I thought, I could do something like `if(@item.Quantity.StartWith(-))`. But there is no function like that in **asp.net-core**.

```
       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if(bla bla bla)

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

What is the best solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `item.Quantity` is int or double

```
@if (item.Quantity > 0)
{
    // Green
    @Html.Label(item.QuantityChange, new { style = "color:#00ff00" })
}
else
{
    // Red
    @Html.Label(item.QuantityChange, new { style = "color:#ff0000" })
}
```

Comment: Can you inspect through devtools and tell me if the style was applied to label or not?

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have a model like:

```
public class Product
{
    public short QuantityChange { get; set; }
}
```

It works when I use below code to set class attribute:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr class="@(item.QuantityChange < 0 ? "red" : "green")">
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityChange)
        </td>

        <td>
          test
        </td>
    </tr>
}
<style>
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
.green{
    background-color:green;
}
</style>
```

Result:
[image]